# Getting strange results from MySQL table imported from CSV file. Encoding issue?

Tags: mysql, csv, character-encoding

I imported a table from a CSV file into MySQL using this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/Alchemy/effects.csv'
INTO TABLE effects
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
(eff_name);
```

The import seemed to work fine and the table appears correct in phpmyadmin but when I try to SELECT * WHERE eff_name="whatever"; I'm getting no results. When I try SELECT * FROM effects; from the command line (windows) I get this strange output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltjm1.jpg

I'm able to select by name in all my other tables it's just this table that is giving me problems. It is also the only table imported from CSV. As I said, it appears normal in phpmyadmin. Is this a character encoding issue? Did I import wrong? What can I do to fix this? I tried converting the CSV file to utf-8 and ansi in notepad++ and I'm still having issues. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be too much trouble to explain my error? I'm pretty green when it comes to sql.

Comment: Windows systems use two characters to terminate a line where Unix systems use one.  The '\r\n' sequence is the windows line ending sequence.  When you specified just '\n', the '\r' was included in the data.  When displayed, that character causes the following text to start on a new line.  HTH